# Invoking C# callback on separate thread via PInvoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, pinvoke

I am trying to marshal a callback via PInvoke from a managed C# program to a native C++ DLL. These callbacks may be invoked after large delays on a separate thread. My current design is finding that the callback is invoked correct with the right data if called immediately at the native layer, but is failing if called at a delay on a separate thread. Here is a simple example of the setup:

**C# Interface**

```
public class Example
{
    private delegate void NativeLoginCallback(IntPtr bytes);

    [DllImport ("NativeExample")]
    private static extern void Example_loginAsync(NativeLoginCallback callback);

    private delegate void LoginCallback(string data);
    public void LoginAsync(LoginCallback callback)
    {
        NativeLoginCallback nativeCallback = (IntPtr bytes) =>
        {
            string data = MarshalUtility.Deserialize<string>(bytes);
            try
            {
                callback(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex);
            }
        }

        Example_loginAsync(nativeCallback);
    }
}
```

**C Interface**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void Example_loginAsync(void* callback)
{
    typedef void(*CSharpLoginCallbackType)(void* data);
    CSharpLoginCallbackType csharpCallback = (CSharpLoginCallbackType) callback;

    auto cppLoginCallback = [csharpCallback](std::string data)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));

        unsigned char* dataBytes;
        MarshalUtility::Serialize(data, dataBytes);
        csharpCallback(dataBytes);
    };

    std::string testData = "This one is called immediately on same thread.";
    unsigned char* testDataBytes;
    MarshalUtility::Serialize(testData, testDataBytes);
    csharpCallback(testDataBytes);

    std::thread t(cppLoginCallback, "This one is called after 5 seconds on seperate thread.");
    t.detach();
}
```

**C# Caller**

```
public class ExampleIntegrator
{
    Example example = new Example();

    public void Test()
    {
        example.Login((string data) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(data);
        };
    }

};
```

The output I see is:

```
This one is called immediately on same thread.
NullReferenceException
```

The output I expect is:

```
This one is called immediately on same thread.
This one is called after 5 seconds on seperate thread.
```

Upon inspection, I have discovered that the data is correct at the scope of NativeLoginCallback i.e. after the line `string data = MarshalUtility.Deserialize<string>(bytes);`, the debugger correctly shows *This one is called after 5 seconds on seperate thread.*, however it finds that **callback** is a NullReference. How do I ensure **callback** does not become null?

Comment: Universal bug, the garbage collector does not know that the delegate is being used by the native code.  You must keep a reference to it so it cannot be collected.  Make `nativeCallback` a *static* variable or use GCHandle.Alloc().

Comment: This solves the problem for me. Thanks!